# When clicked on link, link does not show the correct view. (vue routing)

Tags: routes, vuejs3

http://192.168.1.67:8084/history

This link is supposed to go to the history page but it is showing the landing page which is this link: http://192.168.1.67:8084/

Basically, no matter which path you add in the link, it will always show the view of the landing page.

Please help! Thank you in advance

**This is my app.vue**

```
<script>
import LandingPage from './LandingPage.vue'
import HistoryPage from './History.vue'
import FindPokemon from './FindPokemon.vue'
import navBar from './components/nav-bar.vue'

const routes = {
    '/': LandingPage,
    '/history': HistoryPage,
    '/findpokemon': FindPokemon
}

export default {
    components: {
      navBar
    },

    data() {
      return {
        currentPath: window.location.hash
      }
    },

    computed: {
      currentView() {
        return routes[this.currentPath.slice(1) || '/']
      }
    },
  
    mounted() {
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
        this.currentPath = window.location.hash
        })
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <navBar landingURL="/" historyURL="/history" findpokemonURL="/findpokemon"></navBar>

    <component :is="currentView" />
</template>
```

**This is my nav bar component**

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light px-3 py-3 sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" :href="landingURL">
                <img src="../assets/pokemon_logo.png" alt="pokemonLogo" height="30"/>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse px-2" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" :href="historyURL">History</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" :href="findpokemonURL">Find Pokemon</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'navBar',
    props: {
        landingURL: String,
        historyURL: String,
        findpokemonURL: String
    }
}
</script>
```

It was working previously, but suddenly it didnt

Comment: Any reason why you are trying this without using the vue-router ? If you setup a default vue3 app currently it comes with an example to do this routing in a much simpler  fashion with routes and router-views

Comment: Used this! Great idea.